# htaccess rewrite - removing characters from url

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Looking to rewrite a part of a URL and stuck with dealing with special characters.

**original**
http://www.testwebsite.com/Products/Apple/*/!Accessories

**desired result**
http://www.testwebsite.com/Products/Apple-Accessories

**I would also like to redirect (can a word be removed?)** testwebsite.com/Products/Dell-Laptop/*/!Accessories

**to** testwebsite.com/Products/Dell-Accessories

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You can get great answers here, but you need to take a bit of care to ask good questions.   Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and share with us what you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I have tried only standard rewrites as I am unsure how to deal with the * and ! characters.

RewriteRule ^(.*)Products/Apple/*/!Accessories$ $1Products/Apple-Accessories - is about the extent of what I have researched.

Comment: Great - normal practice would be to put that in your question - you can edit your question thusly... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(Products/[^/]+)/\*/!(.+)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I didnt want to redirect the URL because that breaks the site functionality, just rewrite it in a SEO friendlier way.

Comment: Ok try: `RewriteRule ^(Products/[^/]+)/\*/!(.+)$ /$1-$2 [L,NE]`